# CoreAudio, AudioToolbox, AudioUnit etc. headers not found

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, compiler-errors, file-not-found

I'm trying to build [Ardour](http://ardour.org/building_osx_native.html) on OS X. I ran `./waf configure` successfully, but trying to compile using `./waf` results in numerous file-not-found when trying to `#include` files:

```
../libs/appleutility/CoreAudio/PublicUtility/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:51:11: fatal error: 
      'CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h' file not found
#include <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>

../libs/appleutility/CoreAudio/PublicUtility/CAAUParameter.h:50:10: fatal error: 
      'AudioToolbox/AudioUnitUtilities.h' file not found
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioUnitUtilities.h>

../libs/appleutility/CoreAudio/PublicUtility/AUParamInfo.h:49:10: fatal error: 
      'AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h' file not found
#include <AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h>
```

I asked about this on the `#ardour-osx` IRC channel some 40 hours ago but haven't received a response yet.

How to resolve this problem?

---

The CoreAudio headers seem to be located in

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/Headers/`
```

so I added

```
-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks`
```

to the build script (`wscript`) but the results are the same.

Comment: There are two more frameworks: AudioToolbox.framework and AudioUnit.framework involved. How does the same build behave in 10.10 SDK?

Comment: How can I test it with 10.10. SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Those headers are available as a download from Apple. This is explained in the Xcode 4.3 what's new documentation.

Choose this menu:

Xcode > Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools...
and download "Audio Tools for Xcode".

Comment: The "Audio Tools" .dmg contains only the AU Lab and HALLab apps, not the headers. I already have the headers on my system as mentioned in the question.

Comment: are these avail. for linux as well?